# Looking for assistance in emphasizing card in React

Tags: reactjs

Good evening,

I am learning to develop with React and have a couple weeks experience with it, so please be kind and answer in plain terms, as I don't know the lexicon very well yet.

Here's my issue:

I am rendering a list of cards and I am told to emphasize ONLY the one card that contains the date that will occur next when sorted/filtered, while still rendering the other cards in the array. I am thinking I can apply styling with CSS to do the emphasizing, but I'm wondering how to target one discrete card when sorting or filtering through the array of objects (by adding a class, id, etc. or other method), if all of the cards have the same properties.

Any thoughts or guidance? All help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to code this yourself yet?

Comment: I have the application rendering all the cards, but no, I have not tried coding the highlighted card requirement yet. I was at a loss for how to begin.

Comment: @CharlesBelcher is answer provided working out for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to do it and this is one of them [working example here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/1jbPoWkmesgHEkg9?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1)

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = ({ isHighlighted }) => {
    const style = {
        height: '50px',
        marginTop: '10px',
        border: isHighlighted ? '2px solid red' : '1px solid black'
    };

    return <div style={style} />
};

export default ( { } ) => {

    const items = [{
        id: '1',
        date: new Date("2019-01-01"),
        name: 'item1'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        date: new Date("2019-01-03"),
        name: 'item1'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        date: new Date("2019-01-02"),
        name: 'item1'
    }];

    const highlightedItem = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
        if (item.date > acc.closestDate) {
            return {
                id: item.id,
                closestDate: item.date
            }
        } else {
            return acc;
        }
    }, {
        id: '',
        closestDate: new Date(0)
    });

    return (
        <div>
           {
               items.map(item => <Item isHighlighted={item.id === highlightedItem.id} />)
           }
        </div>
    );
}
```